# How do I beat level 31?

Tags: worms-2-armageddon

As a lifelong gamer, I was amazed by the difficulty of *Worms 2: Armageddon* on the Android platform. After a long struggle, I was finally able to finish level 30, which is basically the end of the campaign. I must say, I am a little proud of myself for this. However... With the gold coins earned, you can buy five bonus campaign levels (31–35). So far, it seems impossible for me to finish level 31. I even wonder what levels 32→35 will bring.

I don't want to spoil anything about the level, but let me just say you are at a HUGE disadvantage when it comes to the number of worms and health per worm.

I tried digging myself in, grouping with enemies so I have a human shield (read: worm shield), and numerous other tricks, but I can't even get close to winning. One time, I got pretty close. Meaning I completed about 80 to 90 percent of the level, but in 100 tries or something, that was a one-timer.

So, does anyone have some nice tips/tactics?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have managed to do this, after a very long frustrating few weeks!

The strategy was to exploit the start where you have one neighboring worm in your section. A simple fire punch (or dragon ball... the blue punch) almost immediately kills this worm, who can then be easily finished off.

Then, simply wait (skip go's if necessary). Packages will teleport near you, and some enemy worms will teleport to get them. These can then be killed in one go, simply by pushing them in to the water. Keep doing this until no more worms come to you (this method also exhausts their teleports). Using this method, I got rid of all the worms on the left side of the level.

Now the tough stuff begins. Making sure you track which enemy worm is next, slowly make your way over to the right, one section at a time (via blowtorch), and kill the enemy worms you encounter. This is possible as there are still a fair few enemy worms left, so you have enough turns to use the shotgun etc.

You'll (probably) be left now with a small nest (3-4) of worms in the lower right corner, and 2-3 worms in the upper right corner. As soon as an opening appears, throw the holy grenade in to the left corner: we need to completely destroy the landscape here. Make sure you still have the next turn free, as this will leave you wide open to next-go attack (use girders to plug the opening if necessary, to stall them).

If you are lucky, you can kill all the lower-left worms in one go. However, as I found, this usually needs 2-3 go's (tip: a banana bomb, thrown so as it bounces little, will release its follow-on bananas close by, so this is very useful for destroying a lot of land.)

Now, you should be left with 2-3 worms in the upper right corner. Use the bit of time you have here to open up the water in the right side of the level. The plan is to do this as much as possible, then teleport away (once you are in danger ie the upper right worms have made an opening in the landscape to fire at you) to stock up on health crates. Once you are safely away, look to use the earthquake to simply drop the remaining worms in to the open water.

If, however, the last worm decides to blowtorch up and to the right (this happened to me), use a girder to 'block' him in. This is tricky with the controls, but you have plenty of time to manage it. Then, with high health levels, teleport across (behind the girder), and do everything you can to blow the worm off the course (eg. blowtorch underneath him, then pack the tunnel with dynamite. Done right, you can simply push him off the course next go).

Good luck! This is a horrible, frustrating level, but so satisfying to defeat!

Comment: This is almost the last strategy I tried. Thanks for the tip for the last few worms. I'll try that soon!

Answer (score 2):

This level has had me screaming in total frustration for the last week.

The best tactic I have is the starting move. Assuming that the level is decorated with the taxi (or newspaper machine on some occasions), and you are in the same section of the map with the bulk of enemies...

I've had the most success by backflipping, then turning around and crawling to the top-right of the section. And then lobbing a banana bomb over the taxi/newspaper machine into the 4 or 5 enemies.

In typical fashion, the banana bomb is completely random and unreliable, and you always wind up with a different result, but if you're lucky, you can knock out most of those worms.

Even though the banana bomb can make a mess out of you too, it's almost worth persisting with the match just to see how it works out.

This technique, followed by counting which enemy's turn is next (so I can avoid that worm and hopefully clean up one of the others), has resulted in getting me to a one-on-one match with the last enemy.

(Only for him to wipe the floor with me or for me to stuff up and fall into the water. But it's the best I've got.)

The banana bomb start is the way to go, but it's pure luck since it'll never do the same thing twice.

I was lucky enough for it to kill two of the three worms straight away, which left me enough turns to wipe out the other one in that section before taking damage.

At that point, it was getting to be a fairer game — but the remainder was avoiding enemies unless you could get a guaranteed kill.

Even then, when I got to one-on-one, I was lucky enough that it teleported to a precariously positioned crate and fell in the water. I had no idea how to kill him unless he killed himself, so this was a total bonus.

(The computer skill in this game is maddening. Some of the shots it makes to perfectly bounce a grenade around 3+ times and have it land directly next to you are rage-inducing.)

So my final answer is to play as strategically as possible, avoiding enemies and counting turns... until they give you the opportunity for an instant kill without taking damage. And even then, pray for luck.

Comment: I kinda stopped playing it after a while. Your tactic is basically the same as mine. The problem is you can't get hit because in the one on one in the end, you will lose hard. I kow the feels bro!

Comment: I finally beat it. Added details above. :)

Comment: How is 32 now? :D Thanks for your answer!!

Comment: Looks like it has the same odds, there's no sections dividing it, but they are alot closer to the water, so a lucky banana bomb seems to be the choice so far. Good luck if you're inspired to take it up again. I'd love to know if anyone tested level 31 with beginner players before releasing it.

Comment: Just to really twist the knife... It turns out level 34 is the same as 31 just a different theme... Same layout and odds. >:( Although it has been a bit easier so far, but maybe that's because I know how to play it...

Answer (score 2):

A good move is to drop a Sentry Gun in the first section, in the hope that the remaining worms attack it and take each other out. Then in the second move teleport to the section on the left with 1 worm and several mines.

Firepunch the worm in this section into the mines. Sometimes it kills him outright. You might need to drop a grenade on top too.  Keep dropping grenades on the crater until it makes a hole into the water, then wait for crates to land in your section which tempt the other worms in. When they come, Dragon Punch their arses into the water.

I can usually get down to the last 2 worms doing this, only to lose to a ridiculous shot by the remainder.

Answer (score 2):

[image]

Finished level 31. Won by the usual start, punch worm into mines, throw petrol grenade. Wait. Punch more as they teleport in. In mean time undermine the bottom cell of worms and once done roll grenades under them. Try to create holes to drop them in the water. Once that is unsafe teleport to safest cell. Protect vs attack. Use earthquake to drop as many in the water as you can. When in doubt wait and seek protection. In some variants of level 31 they make mistakes when you wait.

Answer (score 2):

This mission is impossibly hard, but after about 50 attempts, I did it!

The key is to start in the central cave with just one other worm, use Dragon Ball to knock him into the mines, then kill him on the next go. Teleport to the cave on the furthest right, with only one worm, and kill him.

The key is to then move to the cave with only one other worm after it's that worm's turn. You then have 5 or 6 turns to kill him before he can move again.

Also, when the worms are near water, use Earthquake to knock them into the water. You can kill as many as four or five worms that way.

Comment: Great to hear you finally beat it! However, it seems like the answers your providing have already been posted in much earlier answers. You may need to re-edit your answer to emphasise the new points your adding; we tend to persuade against duplicate answers. Welcome to the Arqade!

Comment: Thanks for the very late answer and for taking time to still post it :).